# Enabling SSL certificate on Mongo using Mongoose and Express

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, mongoose, https

I can't figure out how to add an SSL certificate to my server.js so I can access my API on the server through https.

```
var express = require('express'),
    cors = require('cors'),
    app = express(),
    port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Task = require('./api/models/todoListModel'), //created model loading here
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    helmet = require('helmet');

// Test SSL connection
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// mongoose instance connection url connection
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Tododb');  // was tododb

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// adding Helmet to enhance your API's security
app.use(helmet());

// enabling CORS for all requests
app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

var routes = require('./api/routes/todoListRoutes'); //importing route
routes(app); //register the route

app.listen(port);

console.log('Supporter RESTful API server started on: ' + port);
```

I have tried `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Tododb&ssl=true');` but I don't really know what to do after that? I understand I have to add a reference to the key and certificate files that I have generated but I can't figure how I add those to the connection string.

I have been attempting to follow some of this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

What's the next step?

Answer (score 0):

The next step is to provide ConnectionOptions to the mongoose.connect call. The mongoose documentation (at https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#options) specifies that it will pass on ssl specific options to the underlying MongoClient. The options for the MongoClient can be found at: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/MongoClient.html#connect

The ones you are interrested in are likely sslCert, sslKey, and maybe sslPass (along with some more of the ssl* settings). Note that the ones I listed here might require you to load in a file in code yourself. You might be able to use something like:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var options = {
    ...
    sslCert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, <relative path to the cert>))
};
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Tododb', options);
```

Comment: I have added the following:
`var cert = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/cert.pem', 'utf8');
var key = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/key.pem', 'utf8');

var options = {
 ssl: true,
 sslValidate: true,
 sslCert: cert,
 sslKey: key
};
`
and connected with an authenticated user but I am getting a password error after generating my certificate and key using this
`openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365`

Have I generated my pass and key incorrectly?

Comment: Hold on a sec.. I might have miss understood this thing entirely. Do you want a secure connection between your node application and your database or do you want a secure connection between your client (a browser perhaps) and your node application?